# How can I hide an NSToolbarItem using code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have a toolbar with various options and some options should not be visible in some cases. I have already figured out a way to disable them in my application, using this callback:

```
  - (BOOL) validateToolbarItem: (NSToolbarItem *) toolbarItem
```

But I haven't figured out a way to really **hide** them when I need. Anyone has any ideas on how to do this or if it's really possible at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If disabling them is not enough you could remove the items.

```
[myToolbar removeItemAtIndex:itemIndex];
```

Then when you need to put them back, just re-insert them:

```
[myToolbar insertItemWithItemIdentifier:itemIdentifier atIndex:itemIndex];
```

Look at [Adding and Removing Toolbar Items](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/AddRemoveToolbarItems.html) in the Apple docs.

Answer (score 1):

No built-in visibility property for buttons. Remove it from the toolbar and re-add when needed.

Comment: And how do I re-add them? I don't see a "addItemToToolbar" method. The closest thing i could find is "- (void)insertItemWithItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier atIndex:(NSInteger)index". is that the method I am looking for? Will I need to implement anything else on my delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of endless adding and removing toolbar items in a single `NSToolbar` object to adjust the toolbar for a certain context, it is usually better to implement multiple NSToolbar instances, all with their own configuration for a certain context, and assign the applicable configuration to the `toolbar` property of the `NSWindow`.